# Why is my Firebase/AngularFire query returning an Observable instead of data?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

My other Firebase queries are returning data but a query I wrote today returns an `Observable` instead of data. What does that mean? Why doesn't it return data? Is an Observable like an unfulfilled promise, meaning that we're waiting for the database to send the data?

```js
import { Component, Input, Inject, } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

// Firebase
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

// types
import { L2Language } from '../../services/home-toolbar/home-toolbar.service';
import { LearningModes } from '../../services/home-toolbar/home-toolbar.service';

// services
import { HeaderToolbarService } from '../../services/header-toolbar/header-toolbar.service';

export interface ClipInMovieWatching { clip: number; };

@Component({
  selector: 'app-videos-vocabulary',
  templateUrl: './videos-vocabulary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./videos-vocabulary.component.css']
})
export class VideosVocabularyComponent {
  userUid: string | undefined = undefined;

  private clipInMovieWatchingDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<ClipInMovieWatching>;
  clipInMovieWatching: Observable<ClipInMovieWatching | undefined>;

  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
    @Inject(HeaderToolbarService) private headerToolbarService: HeaderToolbarService
  ) { }

  videoSelector() {
    this.headerToolbarService.getUser().subscribe((user: any) => {
      this.userUid = user.uid;
      console.log(this.userUid); // √ this works
      this.clipInMovieWatchingDoc = firestore.collection('Users').doc(this.userUid).collection('English').doc('Videos').collection('Walker_Climbs_a_Tree').doc<ClipInMovieWatching>('Clip_In_Movie_Watching');
      this.clipInMovieWatching = this.clipInMovieWatchingDoc.valueChanges();
      console.log(this.clipInMovieWatching);
      console.log(this.clipInMovieWatching.clip);

    })
  }

}
```

Here's my Firestore database:

[image]

I'm expecting

```js
console.log(this.clipInMovieWatching);
```

to return an object but returns an Observable.

I'm expecting

```js
console.log(this.clipInMovieWatching.clip);
```

to return `5` but I get an error

```
Property 'clip' does not exist on type 'Observable<ClipInMovieWatching | undefined>'.
```

Do I need to put a `?` somewhere (because no property exists on the type `undefined`)?

I made an `interface` for the document `ClipInMovieWatching` which has only a single property `clip`.

I brought the `userUid` in from the component with the Firebase Auth methods.

I make two variables `clipInMovieWatchingDoc` and `clipInMovieWatching`.

When the method `videoSelector()` is called it gets the `userUid` and then calls Firestore. The Firestore path is deeply nested but I've checked this a million times, and I tried using a shorter path to another document and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

In the view I put this:

```html
<div>
    Clip: {{ (clipInMovieWatching | async)?.clip }}
</div>
```

The value displays in the view. This shows that the Firestore query is working.

To use the value in the component controller I found the answer in a [blog post](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/valuechanges-in-angular-forms/) about `ValueChanges`. This is an Angular event, not a Firebase feature.

I changed these lines:

```js
console.log(this.clipInMovieWatching);
console.log(this.clipInMovieWatching.clip);
```

to

```js
 this.clipInMovieWatching.subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x?.clip);
      })
```